# how to convert list comprehensions to for loops in python

Tags: python-3.x

I understand the importance of list comprehensions but do not understand their inner-workings, thus am not able to understand them in simpler terms such as I would a for loop. For example, how could I change this to a for loop:

```
  arr = [[X, Y, Z] for X in range(x+1) for Y in range(y+1)
           for Z in range(z+1) if X + Y + Z != N
```

In the above example X, Y, Z & N are the input variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply unpack each element one by one, left to right.

Here that will give:

```
arr_ = list()
for X in range(x + 1):
    for Y in range(y + 1):
        for Z in range(z + 1):
            if (X + Y + Z != N):
                arr_.append([X, Y, Z])
```

As you can see, there are exactly the same elements as in your initial code, just `:` and `return` added.

Comment: thanks for your answer after posting this problem I tried it a couple of times and I succeeded.

Comment: Perfect so, Trial and error is the best way to learn.